# Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground

Tags: android, notifications, crash, foreground-service

I am using foreground services in my application and getting this crash logs in crashlytics.
Please guide me how can i resolve this issue

**Stack Trace:**

*Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
at android.os.Parcel.readTypedArray(Parcel.java:3157)
at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplayAsUser(IWindowSession.java:1557)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1556)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:509)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:133)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5322)
at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)*

Code (how i am starting the foreground service)

```
val recordCommand = gson.fromJson(command, RecordCommand::class.java)
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, RecordCommandService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(RecordCommandProcessingBaseI.EXTRAS, recordCommand)
            if (!AppUtils.isServiceRunning(this, RecordCommandService::class.java.name)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    applicationContext.startForegroundService(intent)
                } else {
                    applicationContext.startService(intent)
                }
            }



data class RecordCommand(
val duration: String?="1",
val id: String
```

)

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Please share some code or more of the stacktrace for us to be able to help

Comment: Now, I have posted stack trace. Kindly check it again

Comment: How are you starting the service, are you sending a parcelable? Again it would help with sharing some code.

Comment: Now, i have added some code about how i am start the service. Kindly review it once again

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this stacktrace, when sending data classes as an extra for an intent, the class needs to extend the Parcelable class

```
@Parcelize
data class RecordCommand(
    val duration: String?="1",
    val id: String
) : Parecelable
```

to send it do as follows

```
intent.putExtra(RecordCommandProcessingBaseI.EXTRAS, recordCommand as Parcelable)
```

to get it

```
val recordCommand = intent.getParcelableExtra(RecordCommandProcessingBaseI.EXTRAS)
```

Comment: ok, i will try it and let you know that crash happened again or not

Comment: I have one question. Why this crash is happening sometimes or on some devices not in all cases?

Comment: Cool, let me know if it works and mark the answer as correct then please. Thank you.
Without further context into your app code its hard to say, you could be seeing similar crashes but for different reasons